# See which users have the most consecutive days on SO

Tags: discussion, site-analytics, data-explorer

Is there a way to see which users have the current longest streak of consecutive days on SO? Is this information accessible with the site analytics tool or [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/new)? Or, is this information not available due to privacy concerns?

Comment: You could probably do something with a complex SEDE query, but it might not be accurate due to the fact that some information is not available in SEDE.

Comment: Meh - the top award would go to someone who asked a couple of questions on some company server, forgot about it and so remained logged in for years.

Comment: You used to be able to see this in other people's profile, but I can't find it now. I'm currently at 2,395 days consecutive on Stack Overflow. VonC and I were keeping our progress updated periodically at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-2048-days-2048-consecutive-in-his-her-profile

Comment: @BilltheLizard maybe *you* used to be able to see it because you were a moderator? I'm not sure it has ever been shown publicly.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's a distinct possibility. It has been several months since I went looking for it, which would coincide with stepping down as a mod.